# HTTP Rquest Response in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, http, xmlhttprequest

I have to hit a URL and get its encrypted data response back and use that encrypted data to decrypt data bu using a key.

I used POSTMAN to get the data response back but when I looked into it was just some symbols and not anything like a data response. So, it is encrypted.

I already have a function that convert the encrypted response back to plain text but now, I am not understanding how will I convert that data response to plain text as I have to first get that data response and then only use that data response in a parameter of a decrypto function and with the help of key I can change the back it to plain text.

I know how to change a cipher text to pln text but here things are little bit different.

But as I have to get the data response back shouldn't I have to make a POST request to get it or maybe I am understanding it wrong.

This is my decrypto function-

```
function decryptByDES(cipherTextString, keyString) {
        var keyHex = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(keyString);

        var decrypted = CryptoJS.DES.decrypt({
            ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(cipherTextString)
        }, keyHex, {
            mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
            padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
        });

        alert(decrypted);

        return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    }
```

Here when I calling it

```
<button onclick="decryptByDES('aHJHDJSHJhjsak=', 'ALSOWURNsa');">View</button>
```

I am giving or specifying the ciphertext string and key string as I using it only for testing there is no security issue. It is giving the decrypted value in alert-box.

So, in all I want to know how to get an encrypted data response and used that in the function so read it like a plain text.

**EDIT:**

With the help of POSTMAN I generated code for Javascript Ajax call

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://192.168.168.76:8080/HTMLPortingNewService/GetData?ChartName=widget3LineChart&lob=M&carrier=0&enrollmenttype=0&state=0&agent=0&fromdate=04%2F03%2F2015&todate=05%2F03%2F2015&requestID=499F6BF5E4610454A887AB37AF0814E8",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "postman-token": "ac20a050-a8c8-6d58-4350-66141d519394",
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  "data": {
    "username": "aHRtbHVzZXIx",
    "password": "SHRtbDIwMTY="
  }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

So, now how I can call this response in my function??

Comment: Would you create a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: this is only to convert encrypted response back to plain text https://jsfiddle.net/yktup39e/

Comment: You are not clear if to make `GET` or `POST` requests? use the same request you are making wit POSTMAN. POSTMAN can also generate the code for you, select javascript ajax in the menu

Comment: @shv22 : on first view, decrypt code seems fine, without sending request if you encrypt and decrypt a message both at client side, does it work fine?

Comment: yeah I can  encrypt and decrypt a message but I mainly I have to test data response

Comment: @avck I generated the code and now how will get that response in my function?

Comment: It will be ajax call, make the ajax call. In its success function call your decrypt function with the encrypted data

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `decryptByDES` after ajax complete.

```
    function callServer(){
       var settings = {
            "async": true,
            "crossDomain": true,
            "url": "http://192.168.168.76:8080/HTMLPortingNewService/GetData?ChartName=widget3LineChart&lob=M&carrier=0&enrollmenttype=0&state=0&agent=0&fromdate=04%2F03%2F2015&todate=05%2F03%2F2015&requestID=499F6BF5E4610454A887AB37AF0814E8",
            "method": "POST",
            "headers": {
            "cache-control": "no-cache",
            "postman-token": "ac20a050-a8c8-6d58-4350-66141d519394",
            "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
          },
          "data": {
            "username": "aHRtbHVzZXIx",
            "password": "SHRtbDIwMTY="
          }
        }

        $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
          console.log(response);
          decrypted = decryptByDES(response, keyString);
          console.log(decrypted);
        });
    }
```

And in your HTML call this function:

```
<button onclick="callServer();">View</button>
```

Comment: so, here I will include this whole var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,... in a function and than call that funtion and add that decrypted=decryptByDES... after console log...is it right?

Comment: I tried it is not working...actually, anything is not showing after clicking it...

Comment: Can you post the whole thing in answer? I am very much confused about this

Comment: Done. i add all the function.

Comment: I edited my file but on clicking nothing is happening... I checked in Network tab in Developer menu...it is giving error ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: OK. so start by adding jquery to your html. you have a cdn [here](https://code.jquery.com/)